# Update Panel Button need to be pressed twice to update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a List View inside an update panel, but I can't get it to update properly - each item has a button that removes it from the list - which it does but it takes two button presses to see the item disappear from the page.

Here the markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="DashScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ToDoUpdate" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:ListView ID="ToDo" runat="server">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <li style="" class="<%# Eval("ToDoPriority")%>">
               <%# Eval("ToDoText")%>
               <div class="agile-detail">
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="ToDoComplete" runat="server" CssClass="pull-right btn btn-xs btn-primary" Text="Done" OnClick="ToDoComplete_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <%# Eval("ToDoDate")%>
               </div>
            </li>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenToDoID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ToDoId") %>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:ListView>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the Code Behind:

```
protected void ToDoComplete_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      LinkButton ToDoComplete = sender as LinkButton;
      HiddenField todo =     ToDoComplete.NamingContainer.FindControl("HiddenToDoID") as HiddenField;
      int TodDoId = Convert.ToInt32(todo.Value);

      DashboardController.UpdateToDo(TodDoId);

      GetToDoItems(1);

      ToDoUpdate.Update();
    }
```

Is there any way to do this by pressing the button once?

Comment: When you press the button the first time, does the Click event handler actually get called? If not, perhaps it is an issue with Focus. Another control might own the mouse and thus you need to click elsewhere to release it, and then another click to press the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is Triggers section in UpdatePanel. As your update panel as UpdateMode ="Conditional" you need to specify triggers.  If you are using normal full postback  then change AsyncPostBackTrigger to PostBackTrigger.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ToDoUpdate" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:ListView ID="ToDo" runat="server">
            <li style="" class="<%# Eval("ToDoPriority")%>">
               <%# Eval("ToDoText")%>
               <div class="agile-detail">
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="ToDoComplete" runat="server" CssClass="pull-right btn btn-xs btn-primary" Text="Done" OnClick="ToDoComplete_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <%# Eval("ToDoDate")%>
               </div>
            </li>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenToDoID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ToDoId") %>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:ListView>
   </ContentTemplate>

<Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ToDo" EventName="Click" />
 </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: So, is this explaining that why we need a second click to Update UpdatePanel?